# Can I add category to my custom taxonomy through some function in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, custom-taxonomy

I use my custom taxonomy on Wordpress project and I need to create new category through code.

[image]

Is that even possible? I can`t google some solution for my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [wp_insert_term](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_insert_term/)

```
wp_insert_term( 'category_name', 'your_custom_taxonomy' );
```